# What amount of force could be created by a person "swimming" in air?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, drag, air, biology

Had a question on a physics test, a person is at rest on a frictionless surface and can not throw anything, can they move?

I said yes, by "swimming" against the air and got docked because "it wouldn't generate enough force."

So that makes me wonder, how much force can a human generate by flapping their arms?

Edit: So it will be the mass of the air moved times the velocity it is moved at, i.e.: the momentum created in the air. This is going to be related to the size, shape, and velocity of the arm, but where do I go from here to figure out how to calculate this?

Comment: By the way, if there is some way to calculate this, I'll be more than happy to do the legwork myself if someone can point me in the right direction of how I could go about calculating this. As it stands, I can't even find where to start.

Comment: they can move by pushing air. The force to move something without friction can be as small as you want. although the movement would be small as well.

Comment: @PeterR Granted, but is there some way I could calculate the force created?

Comment: Yes, without friction, F=ma, where m is your mass and a is the acceleration from a force F. What the equation is telling you that for any force F, however small, there will be an acceleration. If there was friction, the force would have to overcome the static frictional force before you began to move.

Comment: OK, found a start, basically, it will be the mass of the air moved times the velocity it is moved at, i.e.: the momentum created in the air. This is going to be related to the size, shape, and velocity of the arm. Since it involves angular motion from an axis at the shoulder, this will probably play a factor as well.

Comment: Can you just stand up and flap your hands to move forward? I don't think so. If you do in a frictionless surface, you will end in pain. Imagine that you do the same thing on ice while standing up. The best way to try it is to lay down and do the flapping in a direction opposite you want to move. While standing up, you can move by just making a net force in the direction you need to move by bending yourself so as to shift your center of gravity thereby making a slight imbalance in the net force and then make a slight backward push with your feet. Once you have the speed, stay straight

Comment: @Unnikrishnan You can not shift your center of gravity without friction other than vertically, and can not push against a frictionless surface, again, except for vertically. Basically as you shift your top forward your bottom half would move in the opposite direction resulting in a rather spectacular face plant and zero horizontal motion. That said, I do agree that the whole process is predicated on moving to a horizontal position like any swimmer would take.

Comment: When you are on a frictionless surface, you should consider that no quick force you could make. Make a gradual increase in force. You need to decrease the rate of change in your momentum by increasing the time interval like a catcher taking a catch

Comment: Two points: 1) birds do it. You're not much of a bird, but the idea should still work. 2) Force is not just momentum, it is momentum *per time*.

Comment: "cannot generate enough force" is a wrong statement as any amount of non-zero force will accelerate you on frictionless surface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the air drag along your arms using the formula for air drag, $F = \frac{1}{2} \rho u^2 c_D A$, takin $u$ the speed at which they'll effectively move relative to air, and $A$ their projected area on the plane perpendicular to motion. $\rho$ is the density of air, that's why it's so much less efficient than in water.

$c_D$ will be [close to 1](http://www.acmelingo.com/flagpoles/FP1001-07.pdf). But you'll have to subtract the drag on your body, and its $c_D$ will be also close to 1 with a larger area. So because the projected area of your arms is little, they'll have to move fast to hope to make a difference...